# Can css selectors act over rendered table boundaries, instead of table dom hierarchy?

Tags: css, css-selectors

Is there a workaraound over css selector behaviour on a table where first or last column uses rowspan/colspan?
I want to set thin borders between cells, and thick borders around table.
The following example is simplified, setting border to the table doesn't work with more complex objetcs where my stylesheet is applied.

The question is if css selectors can act over rendered table boundaries, instead of table dom hierarchy.

```
<style>
table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
}
td {
    border:1px solid black;
}
tr > td:first-child {
    border-left: 5px solid black;
}
tr > td:last-child {
    border-right: 5px solid black;
}
tr:first-child > td {
    border-top: 5px solid black;
}
tr:last-child > td {
    border-bottom: 5px solid black;
}
</style>
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>A</td>
        <td rowspan=2>B</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>C</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: "setting border to the table doesn't work with more complex objetcs where my stylesheet is applied" If that's the case, something else is wrong with your table structure.

Answer (score 0):

Get rid of the extra borders on the cells and just apply it to the entire table.

```
<style>
   table {
      border-collapse: collapse;
      border:5px solid black;
   }
   td {
      border:1px solid black;
   }
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question as asked, no; child selectors will always be applied to the children as they appear in the HTML.

Having said that, you could potentially achieve what you want to do by mixing in some colspan/rowspan [attribute selectors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors) as well as the [negation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:not) & [`only-child`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:only-child) pseudo-classes where necessary, but that could fast become very complicated to write and maintain, depending on the complexity of the final table.

A much easier way to get the desired results in this instance is to make use of the table's [`border-spacing` property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/border-spacing) by:

- Giving that property a value of `1px`.
- Giving the whole table a `border` that's 1 pixel narrower than how you want it to appear (to take the `border-spacing` into account).
- Setting the `background-color` of the table to match its `border-color`.
- Resetting the `background-color` of the table cells.

```css
table{
    background:#000;
    border:4px solid #000;
    border-spacing:1px;
}
td{
    background:#fff;
    padding:5px;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>A</td>
    <td rowspan="2">B</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>C</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```